# Opentsdb Bigtable

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-bigtable, opentsdb

I am using this tool https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentsdb-bigtable to deploy opentsdb in GKE and use Bigtable as a backend DB.

I have two Google projects : project A , project B

In Project A : I am able to deploy opentsdb-bigtable successfully and creates Bigtable tables.

In Project B : I am not able to deploy opentsdb-bigtable. The opentsdb-init deployment (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentsdb-bigtable/blob/master/jobs/opentsdb-init.yaml) is throwing the following error

com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
INFO: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
NativeException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
initialize at /hbase-1.4.3/bin/../lib/ruby/hbase/hbase.rb:45
(root) at /hbase-1.4.3/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:118

So far these are the things I have tried :

- Check default SA permission in GKE and it has Bigtable administration access
- Created manually bigtable tables with cbt using the SA (This SA is being used the default SA in GKE)
- Check GKE configuration to make sure it is using to right default SA

Answer (score 1):

As there's no permission issue (apparently) you may have to incorporate an additional code to make the connection as suggested [here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/issues/2129):

```
 Configuration config = BigtableConfiguration.configure(PROJECT_ID, INSTANCE_ID);
 config.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.APP_PROFILE_ID_KEY, INSTANCE_ID);
 connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
```

Additionally you might have a block in your cloud DNS, or the [workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#fails).

For the DNS you can address the issue by [creating the DNS records in Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access-hybrid#config-choose-domain) for private.googleapis.com